# How to distill 15 unique variables into 4 chosen variables in R?

Tags: r, sorting, if-statement, categories

I have a df:

```
Weight   Age     Race
56       10      WHITE - RUSSIAN 
190      54      HISPANIC/LATINO - CUBAN
99       14      SOUTH AMERICAN
80       9       BLACK/AFRICAN 
200      19      ASIAN - CHINESE
201      20      ASIAN
180      90      WHITE
17       2       UNKNOWN/NOT SPECIFIED 
100      10      BLACK/CAPE VERDEAN 
110      11      
109      9       AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE
```

The Race Category has 15 unique options with output of unique(df$Race):

```
 [1] WHITE                                   
 [2] WHITE - RUSSIAN                         
 [3] ASIAN                                   
 [4] BLACK/AFRICAN AMERICAN                  
 [5] OTHER                                   
 [6] UNKNOWN/NOT SPECIFIED                   
 [7] BLACK/AFRICAN                           
 [8] HISPANIC/LATINO - CUBAN                 
 [9] WHITE - OTHER EUROPEAN                  
[10] AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE           
[11] SOUTH AMERICAN                          
[12] ASIAN - CHINESE                         
[13] BLACK/CAPE VERDEAN                      
[14] HISPANIC/LATINO - PUERTO RICAN          
[15]
```

I'd like to change these into five buckets: "White" with [1,2,9], "Black" with [4,7,13], "Hispanic" with [8,11,14], "Asian" with [3,12], and "Other" with [5,6,10]. If it's blank, I'd like it to remain blank.

I'd like the output to be:

```
Weight   Age     Race
56       10      White
190      54      Hispanic
99       14      Hispanic
80       9       Black 
200      19      Asian
201      20      Asian
180      90      White
17       2       Other
100      10      Black
110      11      
109      9       Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to divide into categories -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Race = case_when(
             grepl('WHITE', Race) ~ 'White', 
             grepl('BLACK', Race) ~ 'Black', 
             grepl('ASIAN', Race) ~ 'Asian',
             Race %in% c('HISPANIC/LATINO - CUBAN', 'SOUTH AMERICAN', 'HISPANIC/LATINO - PUERTO RICAN') ~ 'Hispanic', 
             Race == '' ~ '', 
             TRUE ~ 'Other'))

#   Weight Age     Race
#1      56  10    White
#2     190  54 Hispanic
#3      99  14 Hispanic
#4      80   9    Black
#5     200  19    Asian
#6     201  20    Asian
#7     180  90    White
#8      17   2    Other
#9     100  10    Black
#10    110  11         
#11    109   9    Other
```

We change the race to to `'White'` if it contains the text `'WHITE'` and the same for `'Black'` and `'Asian'`. For rest of the categories we can list the race values individually to combine them.

---

You can also list them individually with `fct_collapse` from `forcats`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Race = forcats::fct_collapse(Race, White = c('WHITE', 'WHITE - RUSSIAN', 'WHITE - OTHER EUROPEAN'), 
                             Black = c('BLACK/AFRICAN AMERICAN', 'BLACK/AFRICAN', 'BLACK/CAPE VERDEAN'), 
                             Hispanic = c('HISPANIC/LATINO - CUBAN', 'SOUTH AMERICAN', 'HISPANIC/LATINO - PUERTO RICAN'), 
                             Asian = c('ASIAN', 'ASIAN - CHINESE'), 
                             Other = c('OTHER', 'UNKNOWN/NOT SPECIFIED', 'AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE')))
```